# How to disable auto sorting of yadcf filter options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yadcf

I am using jQuery plugin [yadcf plugin](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) . first, I've defined an array  `all_serve_products = ["NOS","URS","NVS","NBS","CNS","NEFS"]`, the filter working fine except that its order are changed.

Is there any way to keep the options of filter show the original order of array ?

```
 var all_serve_products = ["NOS","URS","NVS","NBS","CNS","NEFS"];
 var Statistic = $('#statistic').DataTable();
 yadcf.init(Statistic,[
  {column_number : 7, data: all_serve_products, filter_default_label: "Products"}
]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sort_as: 'none'` for that filter, [read docs](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/3e9081a722f827ce50275d26a840ab5f98779e06/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L144) for more...